# RabbitMQ C# connection trouble: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have this code:

```
public class Rabbit
    {
        public IConnection GetConnection()
        {
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
            Uri uri = new Uri("amqp://login:password@1.2.3.4:5672/host");
            connectionFactory.Uri = uri;
            return connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        }

        public  void Send(string queue, string data)
        {
            using (IConnection connection = GetConnection())
            {
                using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue, false, false, false, null);
                    channel.BasicPublish(string.Empty, queue, null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

                }
            }
        }

        public  string  Receive(string queue)
        {
            using (IConnection connection = GetConnection())
            {
                using (IModel channelconsumer = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    //channelconsumer.QueueDeclare(queue, false, false, false, null);
                    BasicGetResult result = channelconsumer.BasicGet(queue, true);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body);
                        Console.WriteLine(data);
                        return data;
                    } else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And i use it:

```
var rabbit = new Rabbit();
rabbit.Send("name.sample.example", json);
```

When I run this code I have error:

RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: „None of the specified endpoints were reachable”

in line:

```
return connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
```

I have login, password Is 100% correct. 
How to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure RabbitMQ is running?

Comment: yes, it's running. I can login to it without any problems

Answer (score 2):

Write the URI without the "host" suffix:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("amqp://login:password@1.2.3.4:5672/");
```

Explanation: The last placeholder in the amqp scheme URI is reserved for specifying a Virtual Host - in RabbitMQ, a Virtual Host is a logical grouping of resources (such as exchanges and queues) designed to support separation of resources for different clients that use the same RabbitMQ instance. By default, only the unnamed "/" Virtual Host is defined. Connections to non-existing Virtual Host names will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue, the creds which i was using was don't have the access.

> This user does not have permission to access any virtual hosts. Use
>   "Set Permission" below to grant permission to access virtual hosts

so i have added my username in RabitMQ provide the access for it.
Now its all good. By default you have the guest/guest credentials in RabitMQ

Answer (score 0):

For me solution was delete System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
from app.config

```
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
```